# Swap two elements in a list by its indices

Tags: list, haskell

Is there any way to swap two elements in a list if the only thing I know about the elements is the position at which they occur in the list.

To be more specific, I am looking for something like this:

```
swapElementsAt :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

that would behave like that:

```
> swapElementsAt 1 3 [5,4,3,2,1] -- swap the first and third elements
[3,4,5,2,1]
```

I thought that a built-in function for this might exists in Haskell but I wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell doesn't have such a function, mainly because it is a little bit un-functional. What are you actually trying to achieve?

You can implement your own version of it (maybe there is a more idiomatic way to write this). Note that I assume that `i < j`, but it would be trivial to extend the function to correctly handle the other cases:

```
swapElementsAt :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
swapElementsAt i j xs = let elemI = xs !! i
                            elemJ = xs !! j
                            left = take i xs
                            middle = take (j - i - 1) (drop (i + 1) xs)
                            right = drop (j + 1) xs
                    in  left ++ [elemJ] ++ middle ++ [elemI] ++ right
```

Comment: I'm trying to write a haskell module that solves variants of the 15 puzzle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle . The tiles are stored in a list and I want to use this function to to swap the empty tile with one of its neighbors.

Comment: Maybe there's a better way to do this but I'll be happy if I can manage to find a solution that works after all

Comment: I wonder how it would work out with the rest of your program if you had a list of `(number, (x, y))` tuples instead of just a list of integers. In the first case you could just `map` over the list and update the position of the square in the given position (leaving the rest of the elements unchanged).

Comment: Like aochagavia I wonder if this is the correct data structure. Perhaps, @jreuab, you are looking for an Array?

Comment: @Andrea Huh, I didn't even know something like an Array exists in Haskell. I guess that would really make more sense here.

Comment: @aochagavia I guess saving the coordinates would make this easier to read. It would also come in handy to calculate the Manhattan-distance.

Comment: This answer does not seem to be correct! Try out: swapElementsAt 0 1 "ab" == "bab"

Comment: @thetruz thanks for pointing that out! I realized there were a couple of off by one errors. I think it should be fixed now.

Comment: Minor additional limitation : `swapElementsAt 0 0 "abc"` evalutes to `aabc`.

Answer (score 19):

**Warning: differential calculus.** I don't intend this answer entirely seriously, as it's rather a sledgehammer nutcracking. But it's a sledgehammer I keep handy, so why not have some sport? Apart from the fact that it's probably rather more than the questioner wanted to know, for which I apologize. It's an attempt to dig out the deeper structure behind the sensible answers which have already been suggested.

The class of differentiable functors offers at least the following bits and pieces.

```
class (Functor f, Functor (D f)) => Diff (f :: * -> *) where
  type D f :: * -> *
  up   :: (I :*: D f) :-> f
  down :: f :-> (f :.: (I :*: D f))
```

I suppose I'd better unpack some of those definitions. They're basic kit for combining functors. This thing

```
type (f :-> g) = forall a. f a -> g a
```

abbreviates polymorphic function types for operations on containers.

Here are constant, identity, composition, sum and product for containers.

```
newtype K a x = K a                       deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable, Show)
newtype I x = I x                         deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable, Show)
newtype (f :.: g) x = C {unC :: f (g x)}  deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable, Show)
data (f :+: g) x = L (f x) | R (g x)      deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable, Show)
data (f :*: g) x = f x :*: g x            deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable, Show)
```

`D` computes the derivative of a functor by the usual rules of calculus. It tells us how to represent a *one-hole context* for an element. Let's read the types of those operations again.

```
up   :: (I :*: D f) :-> f
```

says we can make a whole `f` from the pair of *one* element and a context for that element in an `f`. It's "up", because we're navigating upward in a hierarchical structure, focusing on the whole rather than one element.

```
down :: f :-> (f :.: (I :*: D f))
```

Meanwhile, we can decorate every element in a differentiable functor structure with *its* context, computing all the ways to go "down" to one element in particular.

I'll leave the `Diff` instances for the basic components to the end of this answer. For lists we get

```
instance Diff [] where
  type D [] = [] :*: []
  up (I x :*: (xs :*: ys)) = xs ++ x : ys
  down [] = C []
  down (x : xs) = C ((I x :*: ([] :*: xs)) :
    fmap (id *:* ((x :) *:* id)) (unC (down xs)))
```

where

```
(*:*) :: (f a -> f' a) -> (g a -> g' a) -> (f :*: g) a -> (f' :*: g') a
(ff' *:* gg') (f :*: g) = ff' f :*: gg' g
```

So, for example,

```
> unC (down [0,1,2])
[I 0 :*: ([] :*: [1,2]),I 1 :*: ([0] :*: [2]),I 2 :*: ([0,1] :*: [])]
```

picks out each element-in-context in turn.

If `f` is also `Foldable`, we get a generalized `!!` operator...

```
getN :: (Diff f, Foldable f) => f x -> Int -> (I :*: D f) x
getN f n = foldMap (: []) (unC (down f)) !! n
```

...with the added bonus that we get the element's context as well as the element itself.

```
> getN "abcd" 2
I 'c' :*: ("ab" :*: "d")

> getN ((I "a" :*: I "b") :*: (I "c" :*: I "d")) 2
I "c" :*: R ((I "a" :*: I "b") :*: L (K () :*: I "d"))
```

If we want a functor to offer swapping of *two* elements, it had better be twice differentiable, and its derivative had better be foldable too. Here goes.

```
swapN :: (Diff f, Diff (D f), Foldable f, Foldable (D f)) =>
  Int -> Int -> f x -> f x
swapN i j f = case compare i j of
  { LT -> go i j ; EQ -> f ; GT -> go j i } where
  go i j = up (I y :*: up (I x :*: f'')) where
    I x :*: f'   = getN f i          -- grab the left thing
    I y :*: f''  = getN f' (j - 1)   -- grab the right thing
```

It's now easy to grab two elements out and plug them back in the other way around. If we're numbering the positions, we just need to be careful about the way removing elements renumbers the positions.

```
> swapN 1 3 "abcde"
"adcbe"

> swapN 1 2 ((I "a" :*: I "b") :*: (I "c" :*: I "d"))
(I "a" :*: I "c") :*: (I "b" :*: I "d")
```

As ever, you don't have do dig down too far below a funny editing operation to find some differential structure at work.

**For completeness.** Here are the other instances involved in the above.

```
instance Diff (K a) where     -- constants have zero derivative
  type D (K a) = K Void
  up (_ :*: K z) = absurd z
  down (K a) = C (K a)

instance Diff I where         -- identity has unit derivative
  type D I = K ()
  up (I x :*: K ()) = I x
  down (I x) = C (I (I x :*: K ()))

instance (Diff f, Diff g) => Diff (f :+: g) where  -- commute with +
  type D (f :+: g) = D f :+: D g
  up (I x :*: L f') = L (up (I x :*: f'))
  up (I x :*: R g') = R (up (I x :*: g'))
  down (L f) = C (L (fmap (id *:* L) (unC (down f))))
  down (R g) = C (R (fmap (id *:* R) (unC (down g))))

instance (Diff f, Diff g) => Diff (f :*: g) where  -- product rule
  type D (f :*: g) = (D f :*: g) :+: (f :*: D g)
  up (I x :*: (L (f' :*: g))) = up (I x :*: f') :*: g
  up (I x :*: (R (f :*: g'))) = f :*: up (I x :*: g')
  down (f :*: g) = C     (fmap (id *:* (L . (:*: g))) (unC (down f))
                      :*: fmap (id *:* (R . (f :*:))) (unC (down g)))

instance (Diff f, Diff g) => Diff (f :.: g) where  -- chain rule
  type D (f :.: g) = (D f :.: g) :*: D g
  up (I x :*: (C f'g :*: g')) = C (up (I (up (I x :*: g')) :*: f'g))
  down (C fg) = C (C (fmap inner (unC (down fg)))) where
    inner (I g :*: f'g) = fmap wrap (unC (down g)) where
      wrap (I x :*: g') = I x :*: (C f'g :*: g')
```

Answer (score 7):

There are several working answers here, but I thought that a more idiomatic haskell example would be useful.

In essence, we zip an infinite sequence of natural numbers with the original list to include ordering information in the first element of the resulting pairs, and then we use a simple right fold (catamorphism) to consume the list from the right and create a new list, but this time with the correct elements swapped. We finally extract all the second elements, discarding the first element containing the ordering.

The indexing in this case is zero-based (congruent with Haskell's typical indexes) and the pointers must be in range or you'll get an exception (this can be easily prevented if you change the resulting type to Maybe [a]).

```
swapTwo :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
swapTwo f s xs = map snd . foldr (\x a -> 
        if fst x == f then ys !! s : a
        else if fst x == s then ys !! f : a
        else x : a) [] $ ys
    where ys = zip [0..] xs
```

And a single liner, doing the swap in just one pass (combining the functionality of the foldr and map into a zipWith):

```
swapTwo' f s xs = zipWith (\x y -> 
    if x == f then xs !! s
    else if x == s then xs !! f
    else y) [0..] xs
```

Comment: Yes, finally something, that does work! swapTwo' 0 0 "a" == "a", swapTwo' 0 1 "ab" == "ba", swapTwo' 1 0 "ab" == "ba" and longer list work as well. This should be the accepted answer! Thank you very much, for that elegant solution!

Answer (score 5):

That's how I solved it:

```
swapElementsAt :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
swapElementsAt a b list = list1 ++ [list !! b] ++ list2 ++ [list !! a] ++ list3
    where   list1 = take a list;
            list2 = drop (succ a) (take b list);
            list3 = drop (succ b) list
```

Here I used the convention that position 0 is the first. My function expects a<=b.

What I like most in my program is the line `take a list`.

Edit: If you want to get more such cool lines, look at this code:

```
swapElementsAt :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
swapElementsAt a another list = list1 ++ [list !! another] ++ list2 ++ [list !! a] ++ list3
    where   list1 = take a list;
            list2 = drop (succ a) (take another list);
            list3 = drop (succ another) list
```

Comment: `take a list` really is a great line ;)

Comment: This function is better than the accepted answer, because swapElementsAt' 0 1 "ab" == "ba", but it fails here: swapElementsAt' 1 0 "ab" == "aabb"

Comment: i like this answer because i am able to make sense of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a strange thing to do, but this should work, aside from the off-by-one errors you'll have to fix since I'm writing this on my phone. This version avoids going over the same segments of the list any more times than necessary.

```
swap' :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
swap' first second lst = beginning ++ [y] ++ middle ++ [x] ++ end
  where
    (beginning, (x : r)) = splitAt first lst
    (middle, (y : end)) = splitAt (second - first - 1) r

swap x y | x == y = id
         | otherwise = swap' (min x y) (max x y)
```

Comment: There is indeed an off-by-one error, as you say. The second `splitAt` should be at `second - first - 1`.

Comment: Thanks, @SohamChowdhury.

Comment: This function is better than at least two other functions I commented on, but it fails for the edge case: swap 0 1 "ab" == "ba", swap 1 0 "ab" == "ba", swap 0 0 "a" <- throws exception

Comment: @thetrutz, that should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

***first-order one-pass* swapping**

```
swap 1 j    l  = let (jth,ith:l') = swapHelp j l ith in jth:l'
swap j 1    l  = swap 1 j l
swap i j (h:t) = h : swap (i-1) (j-1) t

swapHelp 1 (h:t) x = (h,x:t)
swapHelp n (h:t) x = (y,h:t') where
                     (y,  t') = swapHelp (n-1) t x
```

- now with *precondition* in compliance with original question, i.e. relaxed to *1 <= i,j <= length l* for *swap i j l*
- draws heavily on an idea by @dfeuer to reduce the problem to swapping the 1st element of a list with another from a given position

Comment: I suspect that any fancy solution should probably start with something that looks approximately like `swap' 0 !j xs = swap'' j xs; swap' i !j (x : xs) = x : swap' (i - 1) (j - 1) xs`. This reduces the problem to swapping the head of the list with some given position. It's still not clear to me how best to proceed from there.

Comment: It's easy if you pass the first element to your helper and letting it return the replaced element too. Great idea, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a recursive solution:

```
setElementAt :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
setElementAt a 0 (_:tail) = a:tail
setElementAt a pos (b:tail) = b:(setElementAt a (pred pos) tail)

swapElementsAt :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
swapElementsAt 0 b list@(c:tail) = (list !! b):(setElementAt c (pred b) tail)
swapElementsAt a b (c:tail) = c:(swapElementsAt (pred a) (pred b) tail)
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like @dfeuer 's solution. However there's still room for optimization by way of deforestation:

```
swap' :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
swap' first second lst = beginning $ [y] ++ (middle $ [x] ++ end)
  where
    (beginning, (x : r)) = swapHelp first lst
    (middle, (y : end)) = swapHelp (second - first - 1) r

swapHelp :: Int -> [a] -> ([a] -> [a],[a])
swapHelp 0 l     = (    id , l)
swapHelp n (h:t) = ((h:).f , r) where
                   (     f , r) = swapHelp (n-1) t
```

Comment: I don't *think* you've actually deforested anything. Unless GHC performs some fancy optimization (I haven't checked), your code will build up chains of function compositions. Those are generally no better than the lists they replace. Have you checked the GHC Core or done some profiling to see?

Comment: No, I haven't. At least it avoids repeated case analysis. Anyway, thanks for your feedback! I've tried to incorporate it into another solution.

Answer (score 0):

For positional swapping, using a more complex fold function I have changed the value of the smalest (`min`) index with the value of the greates `(xs!!(y-ii))` and then keep the value for the greatest index in the temp, until find it, the  index(`max`).

I used `min` and `max` to make sure I encounter in proper order the indices otherwise I would have to put more checks and conditions in the `folds` function.

```
folds _ _ _ _ [] = []
folds i z y tmp (x:xs)
    | i == z = (xs!!(y-ii)):folds ii z y x xs
    | i == y = tmp:folds ii z y 0 xs
    | otherwise = x:folds ii z y tmp xs
    where 
        ii = i+1

swapElementsAt x y xs = folds 0 a b 0 xs
    where
        a = min x y
        b = max x y
```

Results

```
> swapElementsAt 0 1 [1,1,1,3,4,9]
[1,1,1,3,4,9]
> swapElementsAt 0 5 [1,1,1,3,4,9]
[9,1,1,3,4,1]
> swapElementsAt 3 1 [1,1,1,3,4,5]
[1,3,1,1,4,5]
> swapElementsAt 1 3 [1,1,1,3,4,5]
[1,3,1,1,4,5]
> swapElementsAt 5 4 [1,1,1,3,4,5]
[1,1,1,3,5,4]
```

Comment: what about `swapItems 2 3 [9,8,7,1,2,3,4]`, does it swap the 2nd and the 3rd element in that list?  what about `swapItems 2 3 [1,2,3,3,3]`, does it swap *two* elements in the list?

Comment: Good point, for lists with duplicates is needed a different approach. @WillNess

Comment: no, a different approach is needed for *any* lists, because the question asks about *positional* swapping, not the one based on value like it is in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency aside, we can do a fully recursive definition with only pattern matching.

```
swapListElem :: [a] -> Int -> Int -> [a]
-- Get nice arguments
swapListElem xs i j
  | (i>= length xs) || (j>=length xs) = error "Index out of range"
  | i==j = xs
  | i>j  = swapListElem xs j i
-- Base case
swapListElem (x:y:xs) 0 1 = (y:x:xs)
-- Base-ish case: If i=0, use i'=1 as a placeholder for j-th element
swapListElem (x:xs) 0 j = swapListElem (swapListElem (x:(swapListElem xs 0 (j-1))) 0 1) 1 j
-- Non-base case: i>0
swapListElem (x:xs) i j = x:(swapListElem xs (i-1) (j-1))
```