# Swap between implementations of Haskell class dynamically

Tags: haskell

I've pretty much finished writing a poker game, and now I'm trying to demonstrate different implementations of card drawing algorithms, to be swapped potentially each round. I wrote up a class which defines the two functions instances of the class need, and a couple of instances for this class:

```
class Drawable a where
    initDeck :: IO a
    draw :: a -> IO (ShuffleType, Card)

newtype Deck = Deck [Card]
newtype RandomIndex = RandomIndex Deck
newtype KnuthShuffle = KnuthShuffle Deck

instance Drawable RandomIndex where
    initDeck = return $ coerce fullDeck

    draw x = do
        let cards = coerce x

        randomNum <- getStdRandom $ randomR (0, length cards- 1)

        let (beginning, card:end) = splitAt randomNum cards

        return (IsRandomIndex . coerce $ beginning ++ end, card)

instance Drawable KnuthShuffle where
    initDeck = coerce $ shuffle (length fullDeck - 1) fullDeck
        where shuffle 0 xs = return xs
              shuffle i xs = do
                j <- getStdRandom $ randomR (0, i)
                shuffle (i-1) (swap i j xs)

    draw x = return (IsKnuthShuffle $ coerce deck, card)
        where (card:deck) = coerce x


-- adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30551130/8737306
swap :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
swap i j xs
    | i == j = xs
    | otherwise = let elemI = xs !! i
                      elemJ = xs !! j
                      left = take j xs
                      middle = take (i - j - 1) (drop (j + 1) xs)
                      right = drop (i + 1) xs
                  in  left ++ [elemI] ++ middle ++ [elemJ] ++ right
```

Coerce is just used for convenience to unwrap multiple newtypes, I use those to prevent callers outside the module from messing around with the internal cards and insuring the deck state is the same since the previous call of draw.

Now, I want to be able to swap to using them midgame. I have to in some way store the returned type from initDeck or draw in my game data type, to allow me to call draw again. It also has to be polymorphic, so it can store a RandomIndex or a KnuthShuffle.

I initially tried just paramaterizing this data type, so I had something like

```
data Game a = Game {
    players :: [Player],
    pots :: [Pot],
    cards :: a
}
```

Then, I could have a function dealCard:

```
dealCard :: (Drawable a) => Game a -> Game a
dealCard game = do
   deck <- initDeck
   (card, newDeck) <- draw deck
   putStrLn $ "You drew the " ++ show card
   cards .= newDeck -- I'm using lenses and stateT
```

But now it doesn't know what instance to use. So lets tell it:

```
deck <- initDeck :: IO KnuthShuffle
```

Unfortunately, now we have provided an explicit type for deck, it is no longer just a Drawable a, and so we have a type mismatch.

My second thought was to make a compound data type:

```
data ShuffleType = IsKnuthShuffle KnuthShuffle
                 | IsRandomIndex RandomIndex
```

Then we can return a ShuffleType from draw, as we know what type it is in each implementation. However, we can't then pass this returned type back to draw, as we can't unwrap it.

Now I'm pretty stuck, eventually I want to be able to do something like this.

```
nextRound :: Game -> String -> Game
nextRound game newShuffle = do
    case newShuffle of
        "knuth" -> do
             deck <- initDeck :: IO KnuthShuffle
             cards .= deck
        "randomIndex" -> do
             deck <- initDeck :: IO RandomIndex
             cards .= deck
```

Then, in my deal cards function, just calling draw would automatically pick the right representation.

I feel like I'm going around this the wrong way, I usually am able to do everything in Haskell pretty nicely but now I'm not sure how to implement this best. 
I'm not even sure if a class is the best way to do it, and it might even just be better to have a initKnuth, drawKnuth, initRandomIndex etc, but I was hoping to avoid this sort of thing.

I've tried to simplify this a decent amount but I can provide more indepth actual code if needed.

Edit: Thanks to @DanielWagner's suggestion, I ditched the class idea and just provided explicit instances. The code remains pretty much the same, and I can now implement my desired function:

```
drawCard :: GameStateT Card
drawCard = do
    s <- get
    shuffle <- lift $ readIORef (s^.shuffleType)

    let oldDeck = s^.cardInfo.deck

    case shuffle of
        Knuth -> do
            let (card, newDeck) = drawKnuth oldDeck
            cardInfo.deck .= IsKnuth newDeck
            cardInfo.tableCards %= (++ [card])
            return card

        RandomIndex -> do
            (card, newDeck) <- lift $ drawRandomIndex oldDeck
            cardInfo.deck .= IsRandomIndex newDeck
            cardInfo.tableCards %= (++ [card])
            return card
```

The downside of this is it's a bit copy pasty if I intend to implement quite a few of these, however I imagine that can be fixed by assigning the card, newDeck as the result of an if statement.

Comment: How about `data Game = Game { ..., cards :: IO Card }`? Then something like `case newShuffle of KnuthShuffle -> do { i <- initDeckKnuth; cards .= drawKnuth i }`. I don't see the need for a type class at all.

Comment: @DanielWagner  Whilst it's not mandatory, due to me being the only user of the library, I wanted to be able to prevent someone calling initDeckRandomIndex, then calling drawKnuth. By having a class they can only call the correct function. Of course you could could make each function return a different newtype, but I'm not sure if I'd run into the same problem again. Now that I think about it, I don't think I would

Comment: If you know that there will only be a finite number (two in your example) of implementations of `Drawable`, then @DanielWagner is right. You can write it the way he suggests and simply not export the `initDeckRandomIndex`, etc. functions. If you come from languages like Java, the idea that your module system provides access control can be weird, but in Haskell modules are one of the, if not the, best ways to control access to functions.

Comment: @Zpalmtree That need is easily accommodated by fusing `initDeck` and `draw`. That is, instead of offering `initDeckKnuth :: IO [Card]` and `drawKnuth :: [Card] -> IO Card`, instead offer only `initDrawKnuth :: IO (IO Card)`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I was intending to use modules to hide implementations, and was just not exporting my data constructors. I'm not sure how I'd go about not exporting the init functions, as how else would you make an initial deck to draw from? You could do something really ugly like checking if a global mvar was set, and if not call the init function but I chose to just use a data type the user couldn't inspect.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm not sure what that would look like - how would you maintain state of the deck? That type signature confuses me a bit - is that a function which would init the deck, then return an IO function which draws from that deck?

Comment: The `Drawable` class doesn't really make sense. `draw` produces a `ShuffleType`, even though the type of shuffle is already part of the input; what you really want is `draw :: forall (t :: ShuffleType) . Drawable t -> IO Card` where `data Drawable t where KnuthShuffle :: Drawable 'KnuthShuffle; RandomIndex :: Drawable 'RandomIndex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to summarize what was discussed in the comments. You really don't need a typeclass for this. Let's say we want to have two different deck types: Knuth and random.

```
data KnuthShuffle = ...
data RandomIndex  = ...
```

Then let's define a type that can be either one of these, as you suggested doing yourself.

```
data ShuffleType = IsKnuthShuffle KnuthShuffle
                 | IsRandomIndex  RandomIndex
```

Then we'll have all our operations act on `ShuffleType`.

```
initDeckKnuth :: IO KnuthShuffle
initDeckKnuth = ...

initDeckRandom :: IO RandomIndex
initDeckRandom = ...
```

If we have a `KnuthShuffle` or a `RandomIndex` and want to convert it to our unified `ShuffleType`, we apply the appropriate constructor.

```
nextRound :: Game -> String -> Game
nextRound game newShuffle = do
    case newShuffle of
        "knuth" -> do
             deck <- IsKnuthShuffle initDeckKnuth
             cards .= deck
        "randomIndex" -> do
             deck <- IsRandomIndex initDeckRandom
             cards .= deck
```

Then all we need to do is be able to draw cards out of it.

```
draw :: ShuffleType -> IO (ShuffleType, Card)
draw (IsKnuthShuffle x) = ... -- The KnuthShuffle case here
draw (IsRandomIndex  x) = ... -- The RandomIndex  case here
```

Comment: This is nearly exactly what I just finished implementing. Thanks for the help, I'm not sure why I got so hung up on the class idea.